# How to create apps for lower versions in QtCreator?

Tags: qt, sdk, symbian, qt-creator, nokia

I have QtCreator2.3.1 based on Qt4.7.4.
In it I have build options for: 
Qt4.7.3 for Symbian^1(QtSDK)(as i understand s60 5th edition corresponds to Symbian^1),
Qt4.7.3 for Symbian^3(QtSDK),
Qt4.7.4 for Symbian Belle(QtSDK)

My mob is s60 3rd edition, so im not able to even build.
So how do i build for mobile devices with lower version with QtCreator?
If its not possible in QtCreator, how can i create apps in symbian for lower version mobs?

Answer (score 1):

1. download older version of QtSDK from http://get.qt.nokia.com/qtsdk/ (i suggest to use Qt_SDK_Win_offline_v1_1_1_en.exe)
2. run QtCreator 2.3.1 -> Tools -> Options -> Qt -> Select new installed Qt path

Comment: its too big a file, but thanks, will let u know when its done. Meanwhile, where can i find some good tutorials or examples or proper instructions on how to create particular type of apps??

Comment: what do you mean in **particular type of apps** ? If you mean Qt/C++ applications go ahead to this channel it contains on many Qt tutorials for newbies http://www.youtube.com/user/VoidRealms and this link is suitable for newbies in Symbian http://symbianresources.com/tutorials/qt.php ... Allah with you.

Comment: I think that channel will be really helpful. Thanks.
Coming back to the installation, i tried to create an application, it asked me for target of symbian device, but i could find only symbian^1 and symbian^3. How can i do it for other s60 3rd editions.
In one of the tutorials i found installing qt_demos.sis. But i cant find it here.

Comment: To be exact i'm creating a mob app which has sunrise, sunset timings in one page, compass in another page, some web contents in another page etc. I've already published it in android. You can find it in android market by searching 'tamimah'. App name is alsalah.

Comment: It doesnt ask for CODA, but im getting the following.

Starting application...
Could not start application: General OS-related error
Finished.

Comment: I added 4.6.3 to qt versions, but giving me errors like:
cpp.exe failure and
The header file 'mainwindow.h' doesn't include <QObject>.
In between i found my developed app in my mob, but couldnt open it.
so i removed and tried building again, but couldnt get back.

Comment: The last two comments is happening for me.
In the first one, im getting the app in mob device, but not running and getting general OS-related error.
when i tried to build with 4.6.3 it gives the error in second comment.
Someone please help.